# How to deal with unknown entity references?

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I'm parsing (a lot of) XML files that contain entity references which i dont know in advance (can't change that fact).

For example:

```
xml = "<tag>I'm content with &funny; &entity; &references;.</tag>"
```

when i try to parse this using the following code:

```
final DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
final DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
final InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
final Document d = db.parse(is);
```

i get the following exception:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The entity "funny" was referenced, but not declared.
```

but, what i do want to achieve is, that the parser replaces every entity that is not declared (unknown to the parser) with an empty String ''.
Or even better, is there a way to pass a map to the parser like:

```
Map<String,String> entityMapping = ...
entityMapping.put("funny","very");
entityMapping.put("entity","important");
entityMapping.put("references","stuff");
```

so that i could do the following:

```
final DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
final DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
final InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));

db.setEntityResolver(entityMapping);
final Document d = db.parse(is);
```

if i would obtain the text from the document using this example code i should receive:

```
I'm content with very important stuff.
```

Any suggestions? Of course, i already would be happy to just replace the unknown entity's with empty strings.

Thanks,

Comment: I´m not familiar enough with the SAX toolkit to know its API, but can imagine it has a `...Resolver` associated with it. This class would be responsible for resolving these references. That how the .Net model works. I think the concepts are largely the same.

Comment: You mean like EntityResolver? That certainly sounds like it should work, but when I look at its API it doesn't quite seem to be directed at this kind of entity. However trying it shouldn't do any harm.

Comment: `EntityResolver` is for resolving *external* entities (e.g. a DTD), but we're looking for something that handles *internal* entities.

Comment: couldn't EntityResolver2 do this via InputSource resolveEntity(String **name**, String publicId, String baseURI, String systemId) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The StAX API has support for this.  Have a look at [XMLInputFactory](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory.html), it has a [runtime property](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory.html#IS_REPLACING_ENTITY_REFERENCES) which dictates whether or not internal entities are expanded, or left in place. If set to `false`, then the StAX event stream will contain instances of `EntityReference` to represent the unexpanded entities.

If you still want a DOM as the end result, you can chain it together like this:

```
XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
inputFactory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_REPLACING_ENTITY_REFERENCES, false);
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();

String xml = "my xml";
StringReader xmlReader = new StringReader(xml);
XMLEventReader eventReader = inputFactory.createXMLEventReader(xmlReader);
StAXSource source = new StAXSource(eventReader);
DOMResult result = new DOMResult();

transformer.transform(source, result);

Node document = result.getNode();
```

In this case, the resulting DOM will contain nodes of `org.w3c.dom.EntityReference` mixed in with the text nodes. You can then process these as you see fit.

Answer (score 2):

Since your XML input seems to be available as a String, could you not do a simple pre-processing with regular expression replacement?

```
xml = "...";

/* replace entities before parsing */
for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : entityMapping.entrySet()) {
   xml = xml.replaceAll("&" + entry.getKey() + ";", entry.getValue());
}

DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
...
```

It's quite hacky, and you may want to spend some extra effort to ensure that the regexps only match where they really should (think `<entity name="&don't-match-me;"/>`), but at least it's something...

Of course, there are more efficient ways to achieve the same effect than calling `replaceAll()` a lot of times.

Comment: i dont know all entities in advance (as i already mentioned in my question) i only know a subset. and where is the point in using xml for which already mature parsers exists when i end up writing my own parser so i can work with xml data?

Comment: The point is this: those mature parsers are designed to handle well-formed XML. You don't have well-formed XML and you're looking for workarounds to make the parsers handle it anyway.

Comment: well, we can argue a lot, still i have this problem to solve.

Comment: @Chris: I was referring to your original code sample in my use of the 'entityMapping' HashMap. If you add something like `xml = xml.replaceAll("&[^;]*;", "");` after the for loop, my method enables you to deal with unknown entity references. You're right that it's annoying to use such work-arounds, but since you're trying to achieve something an XML was not designed to deal with, a hack like the one above might indeed be a way for you to solve this problem. And frankly, it's not much of a "parser" that you have to write, it's rather a (very simple) preprocessor.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the entities at the befinning of the file. Look [here](http://www.jdom.org/pipermail/jdom-interest/2005-September/015004.html) for more infos.

You could also take a look at [this thread](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5264261) where someone seems to have implemented an EntityResolver interface (you could also implement EntityResolver2 !) where you can process the entities on the fly (e.g. with your proposed Map).

[WARNING: there is a bug!](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6524460) in jdk6, but you could try it with jdk5

Comment: there is no DTD file that defines how to translate the references and i also dont know all the entity references that may occur in the document so i can't create it myself. i only know a small subset of the references that frequently occur but also cant say how "big" that subset is.

Comment: ok, but either you transform those enities to RAW CDATA sections or you could 'skip' or transform those entities on the fly into valid xml-pure-text or sth. like this. Otherwise you will not have a chance.